# Mongoose: ensuring unique value during document creation?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, unique

We are being asked to create documents, in our MongoDB, where one of the fields needs a unique 'human friendly' value, which also needs to be unique and is required. This value also needs to be generated if one is not being provided.

The code we have is in the service layer of our application, but this is failing due to concurrent document creations, so the value does not end up being unique at time of creation. Can anyone suggest an alternative approach that could either be in the form of a function or a pre-create hook?

```js
   async function generatePromoCode (): Promise<string> {
        let index = await Promotion.find().countDocuments();
        let foundPromotion;
        let promotionCode = `PROMO-${index+1}`;
        do {
            try {
                promotionCode = `PROMO-${index+1}`;
                foundPromotion = await Promotion.findOne({ promotionCode });
            } catch (ex) {
                index++;
            }
        } while (foundPromotion);

        return promotionCode;
    }
```

The code is used as follows:

```js
const promotion = {
    code: generatePromoCode(),
    name: 'display name',
    description: 'details on the promotion'
};

const newPromotion = await Promotion.create(promotion);
```